# Showing that two infinite series converge to the same value

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I was preparing for my exam and came across this problem.

Show that

[image]

The series on the left hand side is the power series of $\ln(1+x)$ evaluated at $x=1$. This is what i've done so far. 
[image]

From this point on wards i do not know how to approach this problem since the required infinite series is at $t=1$.
Any insight or answers are greatly appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2n(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}$$

Comment: Write out the first few terms for both series.